# What concurrently bug is in this program?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor, concurrenthashmap

I have one program with strange concurrently bug.

What this program does:

1. Execute event loop each `EVENT_LOOP_PAUSE_DURATION_IN_MS`.
2. For each given task execute processor `TaskProcessor`
3. Each `500 ms` prints queue size of my executor.

I want to have at most one task in queue per `taskId`. So, when I add task in queue, I check whether tasks has already existed or not. If there is no task, I add it. In the end of task processing, I remove task from `activeTasks` map.

If you run the program, then you see the following output:

```
ERROR: 50
ERROR: 70
ERROR: 80
ERROR: 90
ERROR: 110
ERROR: 120
ERROR: 120
ERROR: 140
```

So, there is a bug. I don't know why, but size of thread pool queue is infinitely increasing.

You can see, that I remove active tasks in 2 point of program:

1. In `finally` block of `TaskProcessor`, when task has processed.
2. I remove stale tasks in  event loop.

So, if I remove code, which removes tasks at point (2), then the bug disappears. I don't understand this behavior.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Program {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_TASKS = 40;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 10;
    private static final long EVENT_LOOP_PAUSE_DURATION_IN_MS = 40L;

    class QueueSizePrinter extends Thread {

        private final LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue;

        public QueueSizePrinter(LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
            this.workQueue = workQueue;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                int qSize = workQueue.size();
                if (qSize > NUMBER_OF_TASKS) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: " + qSize);
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500L);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class TaskProcessor implements Runnable {
        private final String currentTaskId;
        private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long> activeTasks;

        public TaskProcessor(String currentTaskId, ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long> activeTasks) {
            this.currentTaskId = currentTaskId;
            this.activeTasks = activeTasks;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // emulate of useful work
                Thread.sleep(300L);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error: " + e.toString());
            } finally {
                activeTasks.remove(currentTaskId); // (1)
            }
        }
    }

    public void program() {

        LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(NUMBER_OF_THREADS, NUMBER_OF_THREADS, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, workQueue);

        Set<String> initialTasks = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
        for (int currentTaskIndex = 0; currentTaskIndex < NUMBER_OF_TASKS; currentTaskIndex++) {
            initialTasks.add(String.valueOf(currentTaskIndex));
        }

        new QueueSizePrinter(workQueue).start();

        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long> activeTasks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        while (true) {

            initialTasks.forEach((currentTaskId) -> {
                if (!activeTasks.containsKey(currentTaskId)) {
                    activeTasks.put(currentTaskId, System.currentTimeMillis());

                    executor.submit(new TaskProcessor(currentTaskId, activeTasks));
                }
            });

            // (2)
            activeTasks.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> {
                boolean hasDelete = System.currentTimeMillis() - entry.getValue() > 1000;
                if (hasDelete) {
                    //System.out.println("DELETE id=" + entry.getKey());
                }
                return hasDelete;
            });

            try {
                Thread.sleep(EVENT_LOOP_PAUSE_DURATION_IN_MS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Program main = new Program();
        main.program();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is at point (2), You are removing stale tasks from activeTasks map. But they are still submitted to ExecutorService. Since You removed it from the map, when while loop execute another cycle, the same task will be resubmitted to ExecutorService. This causes task numbers to increase.

Comment: But if I remove code at point (2), queue is not growing. I cannot understand, why when I have two different removing, their is a bug. But when I have one removing, there is not a bug.

Comment: at (1) you are removing a task that is executed in the Executorservice, so it can be added again. at (2) You are removing a task that is still in the ExecutorQueue, so it should not be added again. But at the while loop You are adding it again.